# the way/how - do they mean the same thing? Are they interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice

**The way** you said that kinda gave me an idea that things weren't all right with you.

**How** you said that kinda gave me an idea that things weren't all right with you.

Are how/this way interchangeable?
Are them sentences I used grammatically correct?

Answer (score -1):

> Are how/this way interchangeable?

Based on experience, yes, they are. "The way" and "how" are synonymous in such a way that both deliver the same message to the reader. Use either to your preference.